# Unable to access Cursor.Current.Position (Access of shared member....through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated

Tags: vb.net, cursor-position, toolstripmenu

I am trying to determine the current mouse position in a MouseHover event for a ToolStripMenuItem. I am using the Cursor.Current.Position property to accomplish this.

Here is the prospective code:

```
    Private Sub pbNotesFlag_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Current.Position.Y)   'New Point(pbNotesFlag.Location.X - 20, pbNotesFlag.Location.Y + 15)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Visible = True
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.BringToFront()
    End Sub
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying types will not be evaluated.
```

After researching this online, I am finding that the prevailing view is that the Cursor reference should be fully qualified, so I changed the code as follows:

```
    Private Sub pbNotesFlag_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = New Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Position.Y)   'New Point(pbNotesFlag.Location.X - 20, pbNotesFlag.Location.Y + 15)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Visible = True
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.BringToFront()
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

I've tried changing the reference context; e.g., putting the reference in a module instead of a class. So far, I have been unable to resolve this error.

I'm not sure why this reference doesn't work.  On the surface, this appears to be a textbook example of the correct usage (according to MSDN).

What am I missing here?

Any insights and/or suggestions will, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? Both 2017 and 2019 can correctly interpret the use of types for shared members when there is a property with the same name. Not sure exactly when they fixed that annoyance.

Comment: Firstly, `Cursor.Position` is already type `Point` so there's no reason to create a new `Point` yourself. Assuming that you can overcome this issue, just assign `Cursor.Position` to `pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location`. That said, `Cursor.Position` is screen coordinates, so you'd have to map to form coordinates: `pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the suggestion/insights.  Tried ```PointToClient``` and it does work; however it doesn't place the tooltip close to the menuitem.  The tooltip ends up displaying near the right end of the window.  I suppose that, because the parent control is the toolstrip itself, ```PointToClient``` actually references the location of the toolstrip.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I ended up using a "low-tech" solution of inserting a ```Label``` control with no text as a "placeholder" on the form right below the relative location of the ```ToolStripMenuItem``` on the ```ToolStrip``` and setting ```Dim currPoint As New Point(lblContractType.Location.X - 20, lblContractType.Location.Y)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = currPoint```

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I ended up using a "low-tech" solution of inserting a ```Label``` control with no text as a "placeholder" on the form right below the relative location of the ```ToolStripMenuItem``` on the ```ToolStrip``` and setting ```Dim currPoint As New Point(lblContractType.Location.X - 20, lblContractType.Location.Y)
        pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = currPoint```  Not an elegant solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The first code didn't work because the form has a `Cursor` property and your use of that name was interpreted as that property - an instance - rather than the type. The second code didn't work because you used the type to get an instance and then used that instead of using the type directly. This:

```vb
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Position
```

should have been this:

```vb
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```

You can also omit the `System` because that namespace is already imported by default. Given my comment too, your code should be this:

```vb
 pbNotesFlagToolTip.Location = PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position)
```